# What is the simplest method to join columns from variable number of files using bash script?

Tags: shell, join

I have input files in one directory. All the input files have the same format and I'd like to join certain columns from these input files into one output file.

For example:

in File1

```
Adam    0.5 a1
Bills   0.7 b1
Carol   0.8 c1
Dean    0.4 d1
```

in File2

```
Adam    0.4 a2
Carol   0.8 c2
Evan    0.9 e2
```

in File3

```
Bills   0.6 b3
Carol   0.7 c3
Evan    0.1 e3
```

I'd like to join the third column from all input files by using the first column as a key. So the output may look like

```
Adam    a1  a2  NA
Bills   b1  NA  b3
Carol   c1  c2  c3
Dean    d1  NA  NA
Evan    NA  e2  e3
```

Because the number of input files are varied, the number of columns in output are also varied. The number of input files are at least 200 and can be maximum at 10,000.

I couldn't find a simple way to use 'for', 'awk', 'join', 'cut' to solve this problem. And yes, I can write a Python or Perl script to solve this problem but I wonder if this can be done using bash script alone?

ps. I tried to search for a solution before asking this question but couldn't find it. If this kind of question is already asked, please point me to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by combining two `join`s.

```
$ join -o '0,1.3,2.3' -a1 -a2 -e 'NA' file1 file2
Adam a1 a2
Bills b1 NA
Carol c1 c2
Dean d1 NA
Evan NA e2
```

First join the first two files together, using `-a1 -a2` to make sure lines that are only present in one file are still printed. `-o '0,1.3,2.3'` controls which fields are output and `-e 'NA'` replaces missing fields with `NA`.

```
$ join -o '0,1.3,2.3' -a1 -a2 -e 'NA' file1 file2 | join -o '0,1.2,1.3,2.3' -a1 -a2 -e 'NA' - file3
Adam a1 a2 NA
Bills b1 NA b3
Carol c1 c2 c3
Dean d1 NA NA
Evan NA e2 e3
```

Then pipe that `join` to another one which joins the third file. The trick here is passing in `-` as the first file name, which tells `join` to use stdin as the first file.

---

For an arbitrary number of files, here's a script which applies this idea recursively.

```
#!/bin/bash

join_all() {
    local file=$1
    shift

    awk '{print $1, $3}' "$file" | {
        if (($# > 0)); then
            join2 - <(join_all "$@") $(($# + 1))
        else
            cat
        fi
    }
}

join2() {
    local file1=$1
    local file2=$2
    local count=$3

    local fields=$(eval echo 2.{2..$count})
    join -a1 -a2 -e 'NA' -o "0 1.2 $fields" "$file1" "$file2"
}

join_all "$@"
```

Example usage:

```
$ ./joinall file1
Adam a1
Bills b1
Carol c1
Dean d1

$ ./joinall file1 file2
Adam a1 a2
Bills b1 NA
Carol c1 c2
Dean d1 NA
Evan NA e2

$ ./joinall file1 file2 file3
Adam a1 a2 NA
Bills b1 NA b3
Carol c1 c2 c3
Dean d1 NA NA
Evan NA e2 e3
```

Comment: I have variable number of input files so it means that there will be variable number of columns in the output files as well. In my toy example, there are only three input files but in my real problems have more than 200 files.

Comment: pipe the output with `| column -t`

Answer (score 2):

For joining large numbers of these files in `bash`, you'll need to use the `join` command — carefully.  (See [`bash` script to find matching rows from multiple CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459789/bash-script-to-find-matching-rows-from-multiple-csv-files-and-create-report-out) and [Join all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903868/join-all-files-in-a-directory) to get some ideas.)

One problem is that `join` only joins two files at a time.  Since the original data files have an unwanted column and the `join` intermediates have variable numbers of columns (all of which are wanted), you will have to approach 200 files rather carefully.  The simple-minded linear approach will work — you'd have to execute 199 `join` commands.  If you tried using a logarithmic approach, you won't necessarily execute fewer commands, so you may as well use the linear approach.

I'm going to assume that the arguments to the script are the names of the files to be joined listed in the sequence to be joined.  I'm also going to assume that all the data files are pre-sorted.  You can build the sort into the script fairly easily.  With `bash`, use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) `<(sort "$file")` in place of just `"$file"` in the `join` command; most other shells will require `sort "$file" | join ... - >$tmp2` where the `-` indicates 'standard input' to the `join` command (and the technique will work fine with `bash` too).  This is packaged as a script that is passed the list of files to be joined as command line arguments, hence the `for file in "$@"` notation.

```
old=/dev/null
ocount=1
ofields=""

tmp1=tmp.$$.1
tmp2=tmp.$$.2
trap "rm -f $tmp1 $tmp2; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

for file in "$@"
do
    join -e NA -a 1 -a 2 -o "0 $ofields 2.3" "$old" "$file" > $tmp2
    ofields="$ofields 1.$((++ocount))"
    mv $tmp2 $tmp1
    old=$tmp1
    # echo "== $file"
    # cat $old
done
mv $tmp1 output.txt

trap 0
```

The code traps interrupts and related signals and removes the temporary files and exits with an error status.  It uses shell arithmetic to build up the list of output columns; `0` denotes the name (join column), and `2.3` is the third column of the second (new) file.  The `$ofields` variable holds numbers `1.2 1.3 1.4 ...` specifying the non-join columns from the previous file.

Sample output on the given data:

```
Adam a1 a2 NA
Bills b1 NA b3
Carol c1 c2 c3
Dean d1 NA NA
Evan NA e2 e3
```