# join with key multiple files

Tags: bash, scripting

How do we join multiple files with 3 column?
expected result on join.txt,

```
server7.txt
DATE TIME server7
20140209 00:00-00:05 99.958775783378%
20140209 00:05-00:10 99.951034588364%
20140209 00:10-00:15 99.946565356473%
server8.txt
DATE TIME server8
20140209 00:00-00:05 99.9585236073714%
20140209 00:05-00:10 99.9506962782437%
20140209 00:10-00:15 99.9379659962486%
server9.txt
DATE TIME server9
20140209 00:00-00:05 99.9486422652602%
20140209 00:10-00:15 99.9433509611542%
20140209 00:20-00:25 99.9318584549217%

join.txt
DATE TIME server7 server8 server9
20140209 00:00-00:05 99.958775783378% 99.9585236073714% 99.9486422652602%
20140209 00:05-00:10 99.951034588364% 99.9506962782437% 99.9433509611542%
20140209 00:10-00:15 99.946565356473% 99.9379659962486% 99.9318584549217%
```

I've already use

paste -d" " server*.txt

but its join all lines without compare a key

Comment: What is the logic for combining the lines?  Observe the `TIME` in various columns in `server9.txt`.  `00:20-00:25` -- this doesn't appear in the other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [commented above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795226/join-with-key-multiple-files#comment32978922_21795226), your input doesn't quite match the expected output.  The file `server9.txt` is missing the row for time `00:05-00:10` and contains an extra one for `00:20-00:25`.  That said, the following should give you an idea of how to join the files.  Saying:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -1 2 -2 2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 server7.txt server8.txt
```

would produce:

```
DATE TIME server7 server8
20140209 00:00-00:05 99.958775783378% 99.9585236073714%
20140209 00:05-00:10 99.951034588364% 99.9506962782437%
20140209 00:10-00:15 99.946565356473% 99.9379659962486%
```

In the above command, we join files based on columns 1 and 2 in the two files and output columns 1, 2, 3 from file1 and column 3 from file2.

You can pipe this output to the third file:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -1 2 -2 2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 server7.txt server8.txt | join -1 1 -2 1 -1 2 -2 2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.3 - server9.txt
```

This would result in:

```
DATE TIME server7 server8 server9
20140209 00:00-00:05 99.958775783378% 99.9585236073714% 99.9486422652602%
20140209 00:10-00:15 99.946565356473% 99.9379659962486% 99.9433509611542%
```

As noted above, the discrepancy in the output and your expected output is due to the fact that the `TIME` column in `server9` doesn't quite match the `TIME` values in other files.

Comment: @devnull also you could use `--header` in order to not effect at first line

Comment: @MortezaLSC I thought that the header was a part of the output :)

Comment: Super! @devnull wicked!

Answer (score 1):

for example if you have two files with one column:

```
join -j 2 $2 $1
```

you can read manual `join` command in bash

here are some helps:
[join](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join)
[join2](http://www.albany.edu/~ig4895/join.htm)
[join3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466662/what-is-the-simplest-method-to-join-columns-from-variable-number-of-files-using)

**you can also pipe the output to `column -t`**

Comment: `join` accepts 2 files but there are (at least) 3 input files. How to cascade this?

Comment: you can edit it whatever you want...three files and etc

Comment: @hek2mgl you can choose any columns and add them by `join` command :)

Comment: I meant something like `join server1.txt server2.txt server3.txt ...`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466662/what-is-the-simplest-method-to-join-columns-from-variable-number-of-files-using

Comment: You should give a complete example (call me stupid, lazy if you want :)

Comment: I am sorry..right now this is not possible...I am in hurry...I shouldn't lose my lunch ;)

Comment: Too add to what @hek2mgl said, in the present form this _answer_ is more of a comment, IMO.

Comment: @MortezaLSC Enjoy your lunch first, we can discuss this later :)

Comment: @devnull While you are basically right, I think it is good to have at least something to discuss and elaborate here. (IMO) :)

Comment: @hek2mgl Agree.  That's why I said (IMO) :)

Comment: I haven't my lunch yet...but I think some guys completed me

Answer (score 0):

This works, but your input seems odd which causes odd output:

```
awk 'FNR!=1{a[$1" "$2]=a[$1" "$2] " " $3}END{for(i in a)print i a[i]}' server*txt
```

Basically, the "FNR!=1" makes it ignore the header lines (line1). Then, for each line read, column 3 is appended to the associative array (a[]) as indexed by fields 1 and 2, so the index of the array elements will be the combined date and time fields.

At the end, all the keys to the associative array are printed out plus the aggregated uptimes at the end.

This will work for any number of server*.txt files without the command line getting any longer and more unintelligible.

Sample output:

```
20140209 00:00-00:05 99.958775783378% 99.9585236073714% 99.9486422652602%
20140209 00:10-00:15 99.946565356473% 99.9379659962486% 99.9433509611542%
20140209 00:20-00:25 99.9318584549217%
20140209 00:05-00:10 99.951034588364% 99.9506962782437%
```

You may want to sort the output afterwards as there is no inherent order to awk arrays.